# Where are the XFCE4 appearance/font settings stored in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, xfce, appearance

Running Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit.

Hello, I was wondering if I could just make a copy of my Appearance (specifically, font) settings because I want to be able to place the file into a LiveCD and make these settings the default on a new installation. If not that, at least I could bulk-copy it to the installations in question.[image: Appearance settings screenshot]Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! It's in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml`. Most of the settings will be set to "empty" if they haven't been changed, otherwise they'll be set to the value. For example, the DPI is set with `<property name="DPI" type="int" value="96"/>` under `Xft`, while the font is set to a string with `<property name="FontName" type="string" value="Noto Sans 11"/>` under `Gtk`.

Answer (score 3):

The default directory in which fonts can be kept is:

```
/usr/share/fonts
/usr/local/share/fonts
```

The easiest place for people to put their fonts is `/home/user/.fonts`. If you have not already done so, create this folder:

```
mkdir ~/.fonts
```

Backup those directory to new machine, then update your font cache:

```
 sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the font files themselves, I'm looking for the config file that says which one is displayed and what size it is and what DPI my screen is etc.

Comment: Probably `~/.config/xfce4` is the one you looking for?

Comment: I spent awhile looking in all the subfolders and files and such until I found it, I've posted it as an answer.